# why does my console look like it performed a command after using fork() to create 3 children?

Tags: c, linux, fork

okay so either I am having this weird bug on my end or it is just a bug on my end and it is nothing that I need to worry about. In any case I am working on an assignment I need to fork 3 times, and i have some quick dummy code here:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    procID = fork();
    if (procID == 0) {
        sleep(3);
        printf("child process: \n");
        exit(0);
    }

}
```

here is the output i want/need:

```
y@y:~/Desktop/playground$ ./a
child process
child process
child process
y@y:~/Desktop/playground$
```

But here is the output that I am getting:

```
y@y:~/Desktop/playground$ gcc a.c -o a -lm
y@y:~/Desktop/playground$ ./a
y@y:~/Desktop/playground$ child process
child process
child process
```

the line containing the problem is this one: `y@y:~/Desktop/playground$ child process`

why does it automatically make it look as if i input the command y@y:~/Desktop/playground$ child process into the console. I was digging into it and trying to fix this on my own but evidently i cannot do this by myself. I understand that once the last parent quits then the "y@y:~/Desktop/playground$" is placed into the console, is there anything i can do to force the parent to wait until the children have finished executing? or is there something else at play here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why does it automatically make it look as if i input the command [..]

It doesn't. What you see is your shell prompt.

The reason is you haven't called [`wait(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitid.2.html) from the parent process for all child processes to exit. So when the parent exits before one or more children, you'd observe that behaviour.

> is there anything i can do to force the parent to wait until the
> children have finished executing?

Call `wait(NULL);` in a loop after the for loop so that the parent waits for all children:

```
while (wait(NULL) > 0);
```

Comment: im getting the error warning: implicit declaration of function 'wait'

Comment: Include headers for `wait`: `#include <sys/types.h>` and `#include <sys/wait.h>`

Comment: Nevermind, I needed the #include <sys/wait.h> my appreciation for your help is immeasurable!

Comment: I could not believe it was this easy and no one has ever mentioned it to me as i have been pulling my hair out for nearly an hour over this dumb question now.

Answer (score 0):

So indeed the wait(NULL) is what i needed to do. If you are encountering the same problem you need to wait(NULL); for the same number of children that you have.